# How can i show can't finding video error when using MediaPlayer in Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

When using a network video file,how can i show not find error?The `OnErrorListener` doesn't work.
Here is the code in `onSurfaceTextureAvailable`,both have no react when the network file can't be get.

```
try {

    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(FILE_URL));
    mMediaPlayer.setSurface(surface);
    mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

    // Play video when the media source is ready for playback.
    mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "ok";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
        }
    });
    mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer,int what,int extra){
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "error";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
            return true;
        }
    });

} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
} catch (SecurityException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
} catch (java.io.IOException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: You can also use custom toast for this...

Comment: @SJ143 But i don't know when should i use it,see my code.

Answer (score -1):

you should check the file before parse the file to uri.and when the file not exist,you can toast a message.but if the video source is network,you can receive an error in `MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener`.

Comment: Actually `MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener`   do nothing with a 404 network file.